# GUI framework for Testing embedded firmware

Tags: gui, hardware

I am developing firmware for communication gateway. Gateway boards communicate with different boards on RS232 or RS485 serial port. 
I want to simulate dummy boards on PC ( OS - Windows 7 ) 
Basic GUI framework will be to set various parameter of slave board like

1. Device ID
2. Communication speed
3. Switching error detection ON/OFF
4. Polling frequency.

My firmware is written in C and C++. Most hardware drivers will be COM port driver of PC.

I need to know a FREE / Open source GUI framework which can do this. I want to re use my slave board firmware on PC.

Comment: Did you ever find something to help?